# Nhibernate subquery

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I'm having huge difficulties trying to write a query for the following situation:

In my core framework (wich i cannot modify since it's not our code) I have two classes:

```
[Class(Table = "Teacher")]
public class Teacher
{
    [Id]
    public virtual long? Id {get;set;}

    [Property]
    public virtual string EmployeeNr{get;set;}
}

[Class(Table = "Student")]
public class Student
{
    [Id]
    public virtual long? Id{get;set;}

    [Property]
    public virtual string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Next, in my application layer i have created the following class to record information about Students and Teachers doing tests

```
[Class(Table = "TestReports", DiscriminatorValueObject = 1)]
public class TestReport
{
    [Id]
    public virtual long? Id{get;set;}

    [Property]
    public virtual string TestName{get;set;}

    [Property]
    public virtual DateTime Date{get;set;}

    [Property]
    public virtual int Correct{get;set;}

    [Property]
    public virtual int InCorrect{get;set;}

    [Property]
    public virtual int Unanswerd{get;set;}

}

[Subclass(NameType = typeof(StudentTestReport), ExtendsType = typeof(TestReport), DiscriminatorValueObject = 2)]
public class StudentTestReport
{
    [ManyToOne]
    public virtual Student Student{get;set;}
}

[Subclass(NameType = typeof(TeacherTestReport), ExtendsType = typeof(TestReport), DiscriminatorValueObject = 3)]
public class TeacherTestReport
{
    [ManyToOne]
    public virtual Teacher Teacher{get;set;}
}
```

Now what i want is a query to get the last testreport of all students and teachers **BUT if the teacher or student didn't take any tests, they should still show up in the overview**. So I decided to take the AliasToBeanTranformer method and created a wrapper object for the report:

```
public class TestOverviewWrapper
{
    public virtual string TestName{get;set;}
    public virtual DateTime Date{get;set;}
    public virtual int Correct{get;set;}
    public virtual int InCorrect{get;set;}
    public virtual int Unanswerd{get;set;}
    public virtual long Id{get;set;}
    public virtual string Name{get;set;}
    public virtual string EmployeeNr{get;set;}

    public virtual string Person
    {
            get{ return Name ?? EmployeeNr;}
    }
}
```

I have huge troubles getting the query right, I tried to see if i could get only the Students and their last test report but i got stuck projecting the properties of my subquery into the wrapper object. This is how far I got:

```
public IList<TestOverviewWrapper> GetTestOverview()
{
    var crit = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().CreateCriteria<Student>("st");

    var dcrit = DetachedCriteria.For<StudentTestReport>("lastTest")
        .Add(Subqueries.PropertyEq("Date",
                                   DetachedCriteria.For<StudentTestReport>("test")
                                       .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("lastTest.Student", "st.Id"))
                                       .SetProjection(Projections.Max("lastTest.Date"))));

    dcrit.Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("lastTest.Student", "st.Id"));

    crit.Add(Subqueries.Select(dcrit));

    crit.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                            .Add(Projections.Property("lastTest.Id")
                            .Add(Projections.Property("lastTest.TestName")
                            .Add(Projections.Property("lastTest.Date")
                            .Add(Projections.Property("lastTest.Correct")
                            .Add(Projections.Property("lastTest.Incorrect")
                            .Add(Projections.Property("lastTest.Unanswerd")
                            .Add(Projections.Property("st.Id")
                            .Add(Projections.Property("st.Name")
                        );

    crit.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<TestOverview>());
    return crit.List<TestOverviewWrapper>();
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, remember i can't add a mapping on the student and teacher classes

Answer (score 1):

there is a handy feature called Future to batch selects together. Given the folowing

```
public class TestOverviewWrapper
{
    public virtual string TestName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual int Correct { get; set; }
    public virtual int InCorrect { get; set; }
    public virtual int Unanswerd { get; set; }
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Person { get; set; }
}
```

the query(ies) would look like

```
var studentTests = session.CreateCriteria<StudentTestReport>("test")
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyEq("Date", DetachedCriteria.For<StudentTestReport>()
        .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("Student", "test.Student"))
        .SetProjection(Projections.Max("lastTest.Date"))))
    .CreateAlias("Student", "student")
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property("TestName"), "TestName")
        .Add(Projections.Property("Date"), "Date")
        .Add(Projections.Property("Correct"), "Correct")
        .Add(Projections.Property("Incorrect"), "Incorrect")
        .Add(Projections.Property("Unanswerd"), "Unanswerd")
        .Add(Projections.Property("student.Id"), "Id")
        .Add(Projections.Property("student.Name"), "Person"))
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<TestOverviewWrapper>())
    .Future<TestOverviewWrapper>();

var studentsWithoutTests = session.CreateCriteria<Student>("student")
    .Add(Subqueries.NotExists(DetachedCriteria.For<StudentTestReport>()
        .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("Student", "student"))))
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property("Id"), "Id")
        .Add(Projections.Property("Name"), "Person"))
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<TestOverviewWrapper>())
    .Future<TestOverviewWrapper>();

var teacherTests = session.CreateCriteria<TeacherTestReport>("test")
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyEq("Date", DetachedCriteria.For<TeacherTestReport>()
        .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("Teacher", "test.Teacher"))
        .SetProjection(Projections.Max("lastTest.Date"))))
    .CreateAlias("Teacher", "teacher")
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property("TestName"), "TestName")
        .Add(Projections.Property("Date"), "Date")
        .Add(Projections.Property("Correct"), "Correct")
        .Add(Projections.Property("Incorrect"), "Incorrect")
        .Add(Projections.Property("Unanswerd"), "Unanswerd")
        .Add(Projections.Property("teacher.Id"), "Id")
        .Add(Projections.Property("teacher.EmployeeNr"), "Person"))
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<TestOverviewWrapper>())
    .Future<TestOverviewWrapper>();

var teacherWithoutTests = session.CreateCriteria<Teacher>("teacher")
    .Add(Subqueries.NotExists(DetachedCriteria.For<TeacherTestReport>()
        .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("Teacher", "teacher"))))
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property("Id"), "Id")
        .Add(Projections.Property("EmployeeNr"), "Person"))
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<TestOverviewWrapper>())
    .Future<TestOverviewWrapper>();

return studentTests.Concat(studentsWithoutTests).Concat(teacherTests).Concat(teacherWithoutTests);
```